# Cannot run jenkins cli

Tags: windows, jenkins

Using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooA8RS3hC6k&list=PLhW3qG5bs-L_ZCOA4zNPSoGbnVQ-rp_dG&index=4), I am trying to run Jenkins cli in a windows 10 laptop as shown below. But, I am getting an exception. How do I find out why the exception occurs and how to fix it ?

Note that I first ran my jenkins.war on port 9090. Then, I moved it into tomcat webapps. Tomcat runs on port 8080.

```
C:\mystuff\jenkins-cli>java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:9090/
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
        at hudson.cli.FullDuplexHttpStream.<init>(FullDuplexHttpStream.java:71)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.plainHttpConnection(CLI.java:279)
        at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:271)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:83)
```

Comment: For sake of testing, just run Jenkins without Tomcat and once you're able to access Jenkins on 9090, try running the command that's giving error. Once you're in that state, open another command prompt in _Administrator_ (elevated) mode and type the following command: `netstat -ab | findstr 9090`. I am assuming `9090` is the port Jenkins is using. What output do you see?

Comment: Your client (jenkins-cli) tries to connect to port 9090, but you said that your server (Tomcat) is listening on port 8080. This explains why your client cannot connect, and the exception `Connection refused` is raised. Or did I misunderstood?

Comment: @Technext - I can't find my Jenkins.war anymore inside the tomcat folder. How do I run Jenkins from command line ?

Answer (score 3):

You should check the exact url and address of the Jenkins instance inside your tomcat.

If you can access the web UI at, for example, http://localhost:8080/jenkins you should run your client as:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
```

Comment: This works. But, I get an error "ERROR: You must authenticate to access this Jenkins." I tried this command `java -jar jenkins-cls.jar -s http://localhost:8080 login -auth username:(password/token)`. Not sure if it worked because I did not get a authentication passed/failed message. I also see an exception in the catalina log corresponding to my password entry - org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: org.apache.coyote.CloseNowException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket...etc

Comment: I don't think there is a `login` command nowadays. You should be fine with `-auth` option. You can verify your authentication with `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -auth username:password who-am-i`.

Comment: @raspy - With username:password myuser:mypassword, I get java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/cli?remoting=false...etc. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command for open the jankins

---

> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/jenkins/

---

but you need to login automatically you can read about [SSO](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/URL+Auth+SSO+Plugin)  on Jenkins

or you are trigger job on Jenkins you can read to use [API](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2015/10/triggering-jenkins-builds-by-url/)

Answer (score 0):

Is running the cli over ssh an Option for you ?
 If yes try the following:

1. Install putty on client machine
2. Generate open ssh key with puttygen, save private key
3. Copy the key to the user which should rum the cli (Userpage=> configure => SSH Public Keys
4. Activate ssh under global security with Static Port
5. Check if you can connect to your Server via ssh (you can use plink for that, comes with putty)
   `plink.exe -P Port_from_point_4 -no-antispoof -batch -i "Path_to_private_key_point_2" user@Jenkins-IP help"`